# save user`s requests with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Project on laravel.
I have search input with AJAX in internet shop, which send requests after type any symbol. I need save 5 last **full** user's requests.
[requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIuXD.png).  I was tried with request->input(), but it isn`t work and i have this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vju8M.png).  my function.

```
public function saveSearchRequest(array $search_elements,Request $request)
{
    if ($request->input('name') == $search_elements['name']) 
    {
        $_SESSION['search_storage'][] = $search_elements['name'];

        return array_unique($_SESSION['search_storage']);
    } else {
        return array_unique($_SESSION['search_storage']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should send another ajax when user hit submit button or press 'Enter' and save the input, so you know the search word is completed

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to save only last five inputs in array maybe you can use php`s `array_splice`  here are the [docs](http://php.net/array_splice)

which would modify code like,

```
public function saveSearchRequest(array $search_elements,Request $request){
  if($request->input('name') == $search_elements['name']){
     $_SESSION['search_storage'][] = $search_elements['name'];

     // this will get you only last 5 elements of array
     $_SESSION['search_storage'][] = array_splice($_SESSION['search_storage'],  -5, sizeof($_SESSION['search_storage']));    

     return array_unique($_SESSION['search_storage']);
 }
 else{
     return array_unique($_SESSION['search_storage']);
 }
}
```

hope i am also on same line as you are and this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can access an array with all items submitted during the request by calling

`$request->all()`

To get a singlular input item, use `$request->input('key')` and replace the 'key' string with your input name e.g `query`, `q`